# Is the vector field A equal to zero if following equations are satisfied?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-spaces, field-theory, poissons-equation

$$\Omega : \nabla\cdot \textbf{A} = 0$$
$$\partial\Omega :  \textbf{A} = 0$$

The vector field $\mathbf{A}$ with known divergence and curl is unique if either normal or tangential boundary condition is assigned. If both boundary conditions are assigned, $\mathbf{A}$ seems overdetermined. I am thinking about can we determine $\mathbf{A}$ from only the info of $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}$ and both boundary conditions? (In this case, $\nabla \times \mathbf{A}$ is unknown and to be determined).

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: MathJax, a form of Latex formatting is supported on this site.  I've taken the liberty of replacing your images with the code, so you can see how it's done.  There's a handy guide here too https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/